# how to use subjunctive

Tags: subjunctives

Excerpted from the story the best by Chekhov : “My dear Jailer, I write you these lines in six languages. Show them to people who know the languages. Let them read them. If they find not one mistake I implore you to fire a shot in the garden. That shot will show me that my efforts have not been thrown away. The geniuses of all ages and of all lands speak different languages, but the same flame burns in them all. Oh, if you only knew what unearthly happiness my soul feels now from being able to understand them!” The prisoner’s desire was fulfilled. T**he banker ordered two shots to be fired in the garden.**

Would you please tell me if the bold part is correct and which of the following could be correct? or is there any difference between them?

A. The banker ordered that two shots to be fired

B. The banker ordered two shots to be fired

C. The banker ordered that two shots be fired

D. The banker ordered two shots be fired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original is correct.

B. is correct as it is the original.

C. is correct.

You need "to" or "that", but not both.